# Select All Checkboxes while keeping track of manual selects jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I've been using a simple select all script for checkboxes for a while now that looks something like this:

```
<span id="select">Select All</span>
```

with

```
$('#select').click(function(event) {
  var $that = $(this);
  $('.checkbox').each(function() {
      this.checked = $that.is(':checked');
  });
});
```

It's fairly simple.  It attaches to an onclick, loops through all the inputs with the class .checkbox and checks or unchecks them accordingly. However what I'd like to do now is make it a bit more user friendly adding the following functionality to it.

1) When the user click the link labeled "Select All" it should select all check boxes as normal, but then change the text to "Deselect All".  Similarly, when the user clicks "Deselect All" the text would go back to "Select All".

2) If the users manually select all check boxes I'd like check for this scenario and update the text from Select All to Deselect All as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is checking whether a `<span>` is `:checked`, which as far as I know is not possible.  Perhaps I'm wrong, but in this answer I'll use a different approach to keeping track of that, a data attribute.

```
// initialize 'checked' property
$('#select').data('checked', false);

// make link control all checkboxes
$('#select').click(function(event) {
  var $that = $(this);
  var isChecked = ! $that.data('checked');
  $that.data('checked', isChecked).html(isChecked ? 'Deselect All' : 'Select All');
  $('.checkbox').prop('checked', isChecked);
});

// make checkboxes update link
$('.checkbox').change(function(event) {
  var numChecked = $('.checkbox:checked').length;
  if (numChecked === 0) {
    $('#select').data('checked', false).html('Select All');
  } else if (numChecked === $('.checkbox').length) {
    $('#select').data('checked', true).html('Deselect All');
  }
});
```

Comment: The .checkbox class isnt on a span, its on a checkbox input which is being looped through.  This has always worked in the past, but maybe I'm mistaken in my coding.

Comment: Yes, but it's the #select element (a span) that you are testing with the :checked pseudoclass selector.

Comment: I agree that the `span` cannot be "checked."  But note that you have a couple typos:  Both the `click` and `change` functions should have a closing parentheses.  Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8g2scukb/

Answer (score 2):

Not jquery, but here's what I'd do

```
var cb=document.getElementsByClassName('cb'); //get all the checkboxes
var selectAll=document.getElementById('selectAll'); //get select all button

function selectAllState(inputEle,selectAllEle){ //class to manage the states of the checkboxes
    var state=1; //1 if button says select all, 0 otherwise;
    var num=inputEle.length;
    function allChecked(){ //see if all are checked
        var x=0;
        for(var i=0;i<num;i++){
            if(inputEle[i].checked==true){
                x+=1;
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
    function handler(){ //if all checked or all unchecked, change select all button text
        var y=allChecked()
        if( y==num && state){
            selectAllEle.innerHTML='Deselect All';
            state=0;
        } else if(y==0 && !state){
            selectAllEle.innerHTML='Select All';
            state=1;
        }
    }
    for(var i=0;i<num;i++){
        inputEle[i].addEventListener('change',handler); //listen for changes in checks
    }
    function checkAll(){ //function checks or unchecks all boxes
        for(var i=0;i<num;i++){
            inputEle[i].checked=state;
        }
        handler();
    }
    selectAll.addEventListener('click',checkAll); //listen for button click
}

var myState=new selectAllState(cb,selectAll); //instance the selectAllState class
```

This creates a javascript class to manage the states of all your checkboxes. It takes two arguments, the first being the array of checkboxes (which is what you get if you use getElementsByClassName), and the second being the select all button. The internal methods could be exposed using the `this` keyword if you want to be able to, for example, have a different part of the application select or deselect all the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking it down in several functions: Let's call the span toggle, as it can select and de-select all.

```
<span id="toggle">Select All</span>
```

And we'll have a function to select and de-select all of the values. No need to iterate through the list as `prop` [sets the value for all elements](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
function SetAll(value){
    $(".checkbox").prop("checked", value);
}
```

Then for the toggle button:

```
$("#toggle").click(function(){
    if($(this).text() == "Select All"){
        SetAll(true);
        $(this).text("De-select All");
    } else {
        SetAll(false);
        $(this).text("Select All");
    }
});
```

Finally we need an onchange event for each checkbox:

```
$(".checkbox").change(function(){
    var allCheckboxes = $(".checkbox");
    var allChecked = $.grep(allCheckboxes, function(n,i){
        return $(n).is(":checked");
    }); //grep returns all elements in array that match criteria
    var allUnchecked = $.grep(allCheckboxes, function(n,i){
        return $(n)is(":checked");
    },true); //invert=true returns all elements in array that do not match

    // check the lengths of the arrays
    if (allChecked.length == allCheckboxes.length)
        $("#toggle").text("De-select All");

    if (allUnchecked.length == allCheckboxes.length)
        $("#toggle").text("Select All");

}):
```